# How can I merge my accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

I have asked a few questions on Stack Overflow under different accounts. How can I merge my profiles so everything is under the same account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have merged your unregistered account into your registered account. If you have other old unregistered accounts, then you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/556877/vignesh This is link to my unregistered profile.

Comment: @Vignesh because that has a different email and other details, I am going to ping the old one with an email to confirm this change

Comment: Thank you. I will  confirm that.

Comment: I have replied.

Comment: I have one more unregistered question. I want it to be merged please help. The URL. http://stackoverflow.com/users/653811/vignesh